# MongoEngine 0.8.3 NotUniqueError on _id field

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

After upgrading MongoEngine from 0.7.9 to 0.8.3, any attempts to save any existing documents in any collection results in a NotUniqueError (`user` collection shown in example):

```
Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: foo.user.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('xxxxxx') })
```

I get the same error if I create a new document and save it more than once:

```
a = Foo()
a.save()
a.save() # results in duplicate error
```

Mongo by default creates an index on `_id` which cannot be removed, and I have no other indexes which use `_id`. Most issues similar to this that I've seen have been on duplicate indexes that aren't `_id` and can be removed, but this is really odd. I am doing nothing weird with the `_id` field, just letting Mongo generate it on its own.

Any ideas on what might be causing this to happen?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest logging an issue. https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues

Comment: I created this issue, in case anyone finds this and wants a link to any developer commentary: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/411

Answer (score 0):

There was a custom save function which hadn't been migrated to using the new save() arguments, so one of them was caused force_insert to evaluate to true.

So dumb...